# what do you mean by utility functions in java?how it is related to Static?

Tags: java

hi what is the actual meaning of utility function in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618895/organize-small-utilities-functions

Comment: This is subjective, but an utility function, the way I use it, is one that provides a fairly generic service to multiple clients. That being said, utility functionc could be made static, for the simple reasoning that an instance of the implementing class is not necessary to perform the function. It's by no means a rule that an utility function must be static, it's mostly a matter of style and design, not one of right/wrong

Answer (score 14):

The term utility function was used by [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) in the book [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) to describe the methods on classes such as [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) and [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

The approach predates Java, and is defined by [Wikipedia - Utility Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class) as a set of methods that perform common, often reused functions.  I would go on to also point out that the functions tend to require no Object level state, that is they tend to be global functions.  And that is why, in Java they tend to become implemented as static methods on a container class.  As that way there is no need to instantiate the class first, and it implies through convention that the method should not have any [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).  Of course counter examples of this probably exist, but not to my knowledge within the Java Core libraries.

Comment: Effective Java: the timeless book every Java developer should read. A common naming pattern outside of the JDK attached to such classes is 'XXXUtil' or 'XXXUtils'. FileUtil, FileUtils, StringUtil, etc. etc.