# Proper way to organize Small Functions in PHP

Tags: php, repository, organization

I have a bunch of small utility `PHP` functions which I made to solve different scripting problems as per my ease. Functions like UUID() and trackUserActivity() etc. There are tons of these functions and increasing everyday.

Say I have around 50 different small functions. And got around 100 different scripts for my application. Sometimes those 100 scripts has to call 3 or even 5 of those functions and sometimes they just call one single function out of 50.

I want to know how you expert guys organize your such bunch of functions? Either you put all of your functions in a separate folder with each function into a separate file and include individually or create a single class and add all those functions in it and include that class calling functions with object instantiation?

I don't think that it would be good idea to make a class of 50 functions and include that class even for calling a single function. But I wanted to be sure.

I found this question at [Organize small utilities functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618895/organize-small-utilities-functions) but this is particularly for Java and it does not seems to fit in PHP situation.

I searched for other StackExchange sites where I could ask this question but could not find a better place for code management. I checked https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ and https://pm.stackexchange.com/ but none of them seems a place for such question.

Comment: I'd say https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Jeto Thanks Jeto. I missed it. I think I should move this question to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spl_autoload_register()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function is a handy way to keep things organised. You can use it to load in static class methods as required by having it in an **'init.php'** file, which you require at the top of every script. Here's an example with a Hash class that contains static methods to create salts and hashes:

```php
<?php
  require_once('init.php');
  $salt = Hash::salt(32); 
  $pw   = Hash::make($_POST['password'], $salt);
?>
```

with the **init.php** and **classes/Hash.php** files looking, for example, like the following:

**init.php:**

```php
<?php
  spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . $class . '.php';
  });
?>
```

**Hash.php:**

```php
<?php
class Hash {
  public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
    return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
  }

  public static function salt($length) {
    return base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
  }
}
?>
```

The `spl_autoload_register()` function finds the appropriate class, based on the function you provide as an argument, when it encounters an instantiation or use of static method for the first time in your code.

You can use this to your advantage by grouping together related functions as static methods. For example, my **classes** directory for a particular project has:

```
Config.php              Cookie.php           DB.php
Err.php                 FormatError.php      Hash.php
Input.php               MismatchError.php    Redirect.php
RequiredFieldError.php  Session.php          StringLengthError.php
Token.php               UniqueItemError.php  User.php
Validate.php
```

which contain, among other things, static methods related to each other. They're only ever loaded if Php encounters their name anywhere in any of my scripts that have the init.php file included.

Comment: Wow Man! You are just a SuperHero. I didn't know about this spl_autoload_register(). Although I have used Autoload.php like things but never really looked in. Just Wondrous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

compuphys's answer really helped me out. For those who are already using `composer`'s `Autoload.php` file then you have to register your spl function instead of calling anonymously like below

```
function myAutoLoader($className)
{
    $file = __dir__.'/classes/'.$className'.php';
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
         include_once($file);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```